# What do AHRS, EHRS, QHRS mean on a transcript?

Tags: transcript-of-records

What do the abbreviations AHRS, EHRS, and QHRS mean on a transcript?

My guess would be:

1. AHRS = "all hours"
2. EHRS = "earned hours"
3. QHRS = "quality(?) hours"

What are the differences between these things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Attempted Hours
- Earned Hours
- Quality Hours

[Source](http://www.suu.edu/ss/registrar/transcript-explain.html)

Comment: In the US federal financial aid system there are requirements that students "earn" a certain number of credit hours within a certain amount of time and that attempted (sum of unearned (basically failed) hours and earned hours) cannot exceed certain limits.  Quality hours have earned hours multiplied by GPA points (4 for an A, 3 for a B, etc.)

Comment: @BrianBorchers: So, when an employer asks, for example, how many graduate hours I have, what do I give them: the attempted, earned, or quality hours?

Comment: @Geremia Earned, typically.